# convert a char array with a utf8 character to it's hex

Tags: c++, unicode, utf-8, ascii

I have the following example of code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {

    char test[] = "êêê"; // test[10] won't compile. Use test[13] or just test[]

    std::cout << "The string " << test << " consists of " << sizeof test << " bytes: ";
    for (std::size_t n = 0; n < sizeof test; ++n)
        std::cout << std::hex << +(unsigned char)test[n] << ' ';

    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

which on a c++ online shell like cpp.sh gives me the following result:

```
The string êêê consists of 7 bytes: c3 aa c3 aa c3 aa 0
```

and when I try it on VS2013 it gives me the result:

```
The string êêê consists of 7 bytes: a8 ba a8 ba a8 ba 0
```

Could someone explain to me why this is, and how to fix it? I've tried to change the character set, but it still gave the same thing.

Comment: C/C++ are sort of arms-length about character encodings.  What happens with `char test[] = "\u00e9\u00e9\u00e9";`?

Comment: VS2013 may, or may not, use utf-8 for the source code. When you use a web browser, it might translate the characters before sending them.

Comment: @Eljay when i try this, the result is: a8 a6 a8 a6 a8 a6 0,
Bo Persson i've try to change to UTF-8 in Project property -> c/c++ -> command line = /utf-8 and it's still the samething :(

Comment: @RenanMoura • using the code in your question, and using my C++ compiler, I'm seeing `The string êêê consists of 7 bytes: c3 aa c3 aa c3 aa 0`.  I've saved my test.cpp source file in UTF-8 format, without BOM.

Comment: @RenanMoura • in VS2013, make sure the source file is being saved with "Unicode (UTF-8 without signature)" format.

Comment: In my previous comment, I should have used `\u00EA`.  I can't edit it now, past edit expiry.  This is what happens when you try to do Unicode from memory.

Comment: You, your source code editor, your source code file and your compiler have to agree on what the [/source-charset](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt708819.aspx) _is_.  Then you can tell the compiler what [/execution-charset](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt708818.aspx) you _want_.

Comment: @Eljay thank you all for the answers, but now i'm getting the following result:  The string ├¬├¬├¬ consists of 7 bytes: c3 aa c3 aa c3 aa 0 anyone know why i'm getting "├¬├¬├¬" ? i just saved the source file with Unicode (UTF-8 without encoding)

Comment: At a guess, your output is going to something that does not understand UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: @Eljay i'm using windows console, do you know how can i fix it?

Comment: @RenanMoura • I assume you are using the latest version of Windows 10.  Here's an answer on using Unicode with the console:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388490/how-to-use-unicode-characters-in-windows-command-line

Comment: i'm using windows 7 but i'll take a look at this

Comment: i've solved my problems thank you all for the answers, now i have a doubt, how can i use my code to convert the same values like 'c3 aa' to its character again? like 'ê', i've tried using istringstream >> hex >> c; and still can't do it

Comment: @RenanMoura you should use a Unicode library, like ICONV or ICU. Or  if you are using C++11 or later, look at `std::wstring_convert`.